# How to show that a triple $(P, S, 1)$ constitutes a Peano System?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, natural-numbers, number-systems, peano-axioms

Mendelson (in Number Systems & the Foundations of Analysis) defines a Peano System as a triple $(P, S, 1)$ consisting of a set $P$, a distinguished element $1 \in P$, and a singulary operation $S :P \mapsto P$, where $S(n)$ is called "the successor of $n$", such that

1. $1$ is not the successor of any other element
2. $S(x) = S(y) \implies x = y$
3. The Principle of Mathematical Induction holds -- namely, for any subset $B \subseteq P$ that contains the distinguished element $1$ and is closed under $S$, then $B = P$.

My question is: is it possible to show that a triple satisfies these properties? In particular, how might one rigorously show that property 3 holds?

For example, let $P$ be the set of positive even integers, $S = x \mapsto x + 2$, and the distinguished element is $0$. Showing that properties 1 and 2 are met seems simple enough, but it's unclear to me how one might show that 3 holds for an arbitrary set.

I know that in this example, we need what Mendelson calls  the "Iteration Theorem" and what other authors seem to call the "Recursion Theorem" to define addition over the natural numbers to be rigorous about our definition of $S$. But that seems a bit circular, since we haven't yet shown that our triple is even a Peano System yet.

I would appreciate any efforts to illuminate my muddled thinking here :)

Comment: "Equivalent set is supposed" to mean something?

Comment: Thanks, I edited that for clarity

Comment: Why would it hold for an arbitrary triple?

Comment: I edited the title for clarity. Thanks @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: To show it holds in your case you can argue that if there is an element in $P-B$ then there is a least element $n\ne 0.$ But then, $n-2\in B,$ so by closure $S(n-2)=n\in B$ after all.

Comment: The main question in your post with the phrase "arbitrary triple" still needs to be fixed. An arbitrary triple $(P,S,1)$ does not satisfy those conditions.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen - Right. Note, though, that this uses the well-order of $\mathbb{N}$, which is equivalent to 3 over $(\mathbb{N}, 0, S)$, and in that case we just take it as our definition of $\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: I see. But if all I have is the definition of a Peano System and some basic facts about the algebra of sets, i don't necessarily have operators $+$ and $-$ -- I need to define those inductively using the iteration theorem and then use those to define $S$. But the iteration theorem requires that I'm working with a Peano System, which I need the iteration theorem to properly define. That's the circularity I was getting at -- sorry I'm realizing my question was super unclear because it seemed to assume I have the operators I need already

Comment: @Hugo Why don't you have those here? They are restrictions of the ones defined on $\mathbb N.$ And surely you assume (or prove from a set theoretical construction) that $(\mathbb N,S,0)$ is a Peano system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it depends on how you define your candidate Peano structure.

What property (3) guarantees is that your set $P$ is *inductively defined*, that is every element $x\in P$ can be written as $S(S(\ldots(S(1))\ldots))$, that is, $P$ contains no other "exotic" elements.

When you define a Peano system you are defining a class of mathematical structures satisfying certain properties. These structures are precisely the sets which have the structure of the natural numbers.

So when we define the natural numbers in set theory we first build a set $\mathbb N$ which is closed under an operation called the successor, given by $S(x) := \{x,\{x\}\}$, and $0 := \emptyset$. Set theory guarantees the existence of such a set, called $N$. In fact there are many such sets, which may have too many elements. To fix this, we define

$$\mathbb N := \bigcap\{x\in \mathscr P(N)\ |\ 0\in x\ \wedge\ \forall z. z\in x\to S(z)\in x\}.$$

We then show that $(\mathbb N,0,S)$ satisfies the property of being a Peano structure. In particular, for property (3) we have that given $U\subset \mathbb N\subset N$ containing $0$ and closed under $S$, we know from the definition of $\mathbb N$ (since it is an intersection), that $\mathbb N\subset U$ and thus $U =\mathbb N$.

This is how one would proceed. For the even naturals $\mathbb E\subset\mathbb N$, you would either define them similarly (replacing $S$ with $S\circ S$) to $\mathbb N$ and use the same argument, or you would have to use the fact that $\mathbb N$ satisfies property (3).

Now that you know that $\mathbb N$ is a Peano system, you can use your iteration theorem (I assume this gives you a way to define recursive functions, or some version of the [Knaster-Tarski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem)) to define the addition and multiplication operations.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know of any references I can look at about this formulation for further reading?

Comment: @Hugo I realize this is a bit late, but I just found this nice reference [Intuitionistic set theory](http://publish.uwo.ca/~jbell/INTBOOK(Repaired).pdf) by John Bell, which discusses this clearly in Chapter II. The plus side of this is that the arguments are constructive!